# Error ITMS 90086 When submitting app. Nothing Helps

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture, app-store, admob, submit

I am trying to submit my app to the store but it gives this error. I google it and search all stack overflow questions related about this error and as a result I try many things but nothing helps. Where am i doing wrong ? Any help ?

Thinks that I try:
1. Set `Build Active Architecture Only = No`
2. Set `Architectures`  to Standart
3. Deletting pod file and re-install it

Comment: Sounds like wrong _Scripting Backend_ in Build Player Settings / Other Settings. s. [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/980007/xcode-error-90086.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your settings from File->Build Settings. Select iOS and click **Player Settings**. On the right side, Change **Scripting Backend** from **Mono2x** to **IL2CPP**. Then change **Architecture** to **Universal**.